# Migrating Trac Wiki

Tags: migration, wiki, trac

I am trying to move Trac data from an old server at my workplace to a new server but I am stuck on the last step of migrating our wiki data. We use Trac 1.0.1 and are trying to update to Trac 1.2. The part I am stuck on is dumping the wiki. I have been trying to use

trac-admin wiki dump

This works for my tests but when I try to use it on the actual wiki I get an error saying that the filename is too long. This happens because the hierarchical files try to make a filename like this

child1%2child2%2child3%2child4%2child5%2.....

instead of

child1/child2/child3/child4/child5/.....

Since linux is seeing this path as one name it throws an error saying that the file name is too long. Has anyone ran into this problem before and have a solution for it????

I have also tried making a hotcopy of trac and transfering it but this doesnt work either. If anyone knows where the wikis are stored and how  to copy that from our old server to our new server that would be the most optimal solution I am looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trac wiki migration problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954329/trac-wiki-migration-problems)

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean by hotcopy "doesn't work".